# Touch Screen on Android

Tags: android, linux, touchscreen

Does anyone know where the touch screen sensing is implemented in the Android 2.x.x kernel is? If it is implemented in the official Linux kernel, that's fine too. I just need to know where I can see the implementation code.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you're asking for is driver code implemented by the phone manufacturers.  In other words, it's not open source code that you have access to.

Android receives position information from the phone's driver level and reacts according to that.  There is no direct hardware > software connection.

Sorry! :(

Hope this helped.

Comment: Ah, did a quick directory search in the downloaded version of linux 3.0 and found some touchscreen related code under "drivers/input/touchscreen" DUH! I also looked in the android git repos and found it there too (http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=kernel/common.git;a=tree;f=drivers/input/touchscreen;hb=HEAD)!

Comment: There definitely is generic code! :)  It just isn't guaranteed to work on any given device, unfortunately.  You should use the abstracted environment that Android provides you.

Comment: Well, I'm gonna order the controller that is specifically supported by the "generic" code... It's the Analog Devices ad7879. It's got it's own source and header files built into linux.

Comment: They are the same files they provide in their git repo (yes, their drivers are open-source).

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I misunderstood your question.  I was thinking you were trying to develop something with the ndk with direct touchscreen access.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'm probably gonna need it... :)